# Django and Gunicorn not talking

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

Yesterday I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535573/cant-reach-django-default-app-via-gunicorn-on-aws-ec2-instance) which no one was able to answer so I've continued working on it and decided to set up the simplest possible scenario.  I'm now trying to run the default Django (1.6) application (displays "It worked!") using Gunicorn (v. 18) as my HTTP server and Nginx (v. 1.4.1) as my reverse proxy.  They're running on an AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu Server 13.10).  When I try to start Gunicorn, I get this error:

```
Starting testdj as ubuntu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/testdj/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==18.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/testdj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/testdj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/testdj/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
ImportError: No module named app.wsgiapp
```

I installed nginx and gunicorn using APT.  I also installed virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper and am running Django inside a virtual environment.  I'm running the application as the default EC2 user "ubuntu".  The Django app "testdj" is in /usr/share/nginx/html/testdj and ubuntu owns the directory tree.  I haven't changed Django's default wsgi.py file.

Here's my "start-gunicorn" script:

```
#!/bin/bash
NAME="testdj"
DJANGODIR=/usr/share/nginx/html/testdj
USER=ubuntu
GROUP=ubuntu
NUM_WORKERS=3
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=testdj.settings
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=testdj.wsgi
WORKON_HOME=/home/ubuntu/venv
source `which virtualenvwrapper.sh`
workon $NAME
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGO_DIR:$PYTHONPATH
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log \
  --error-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/error.log \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=0.0.0.0:8000
```

Here's my nginx virtual host config file:

```
upstream app_server {
    # For a TCP configuration:
    server 0.0.0.0:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name _;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/testdj/static;
    location / {
        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }
    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/testdj/static;
    }
}
```

Now what's interesting is that I created this test.py file and put it in the top level of my Django app's directory:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -
def app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    data = 'Hello, world!!\n'
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [
        ('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(data)))
    ]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return iter([data])
```

I then ran the command "gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 test:app" and I can see the "Hello, world" output so I know that nginx and gunicorn and the Python file are talking.  It's just that gunicorn isn't talking to Django.  I thought that perhaps the problem was that I had installed gunicorn globally (with APT) and that was causing it to not be able to find the app.wsgiapp file so I also installed gunicorn into the virtual environment.  However, that didn't fix the problem.  There's nothing in my PYTHONPATH variable (I've never needed to have anything in it with my other Django applications.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  There have to be thousands of websites that are running Django with nginx and Gunicorn and they work.  What am I doing wrong???  I've read all the Gunicorn docs, the Django doc on WSGI, and numerous articles on Gunicorn and nginx, all to no avail.  I've been stuck on this problem for three days now.  Any help would be *greatly* appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What's the directory layout, does exist a file named ``wsgiapp`` in a module?

Answer (score 0):

I repeated my configuration process line-for-line on my Linode server and had no problems at all.  I have to assume that this problem has something to do with the way AWS EC2 instances are configured, probably with respect to security.  The only change I made was to bind to port 127.0.0.1:8000.  I'll have to create a gist to my files to show others how I did it in case anyone's interested.