# Gunicorn - Can't Access Django Project (Browser Times Out)

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Using AWS and Gunicorn, my Django site is accessible and fully functional if I spin up the Django's built-in server, but I can't access it through Gunicorn.

If I try:

`gunicorn MyApp.wsgi`

It seems to start up:

```
[2015-11-18 17:53:30 +0000] [18752] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-11-18 17:53:30 +0000] [18752] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8001 (18752)
[2015-11-18 17:53:30 +0000] [18752] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2015-11-18 17:53:30 +0000] [18755] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18755
```

But the browser just returns the Nginx splash page at the basic URL/IP address and times out when attempting to visit `<url>:8001` or `<ip_address>:8001`.

I get the same result if I run:

`gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8001`

EDIT: If I try the same command with the specific URL in place of `0.0.0.0` it outputs the following:

```
[2015-11-18 18:24:17 +0000] [18902] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-11-18 18:24:17 +0000] [18902] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-18 18:24:18 +0000] [18902] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-18 18:24:19 +0000] [18902] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-18 18:24:20 +0000] [18902] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-18 18:24:21 +0000] [18902] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
[2015-11-18 18:24:22 +0000] [18902] [ERROR] Can't connect to ('myurl.xyz', 8001)
```

If I use the server's IP address, I see:

```
[2015-11-18 18:26:22 +0000] [18911] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
[2015-11-18 18:26:22 +0000] [18911] [ERROR] Invalid address: ('<my_ip>', 8001)
```

I spent 3 days unsuccessfully trying to get uWSGI to work and I'm on day 2 with Gunicorn and I can't seem to get past this point with either. None of the docs or tutorials specify what to do if this first step doesn't work. I'm very new at this, perhaps there is something simple that I'm overlooking that everyone else just assumes would be taken care of?

All relevant IP addresses and urls are set correctly in the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` portion of Django's settings module.

Comment: You only mention nginx in passing, but you have clearly installed that as the reverse proxy. So you need to post its configuration here.

Comment: Ok, that actually clears a lot of this up. I was under the impression that this would work regardless of Nginx! I will look for the Nginx configuration file.

Comment: Looking at the Gunicorn docs, it seems that I should be able to get Gunicorn working without configuring Nginx at all. I was really hoping to solve this issue before working through the myriad of troubles I will face by trying to set Nginx up, since I will need a way to check if future solutions are working. Is this possible if I stop the Nginx service?  https://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/run.html#django

Comment: You could, but port 8000 is not open to the outside by default; you'd either need to fiddle with your load balancer/firewall settings to open it, or run gunicorn on port 80 (which will mean killing nginx and starting gunicorn as the superuser). Much easier to just get the nginx settings right; there is a perfectly usable configuration on the [gunicorn deploy docs page](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deploy.html).

Comment: Ok thanks so much for explaining that! I've adopted that example configuration and am now trying to fiddle it into submission. Regardless of how it turns out, I think the question I had here is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) indicated, Amazon doesn't seem to allow me to do what I was trying to do here without additional configuration.

I took the advice and configured Nginx and now I am able to use

`gunicorn MyApp.wsgi:application --bind=172.31.21.65:8000`

to spin it up.